# Operation of Fruit Blender-Mixer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, design, manufacturing-engineering

I was wondering how blenders used in the kitchen for the purpose of creating smoothies, soups, etc. operate, particularly, how the rotation of their blade is achieved, i.e. what sort of motor is used for this purpose. I am additionally interested in finding additional Bibliography in the bespoked subject, as well as the industrial methods used to generate each component of blenders (meaning not only the mechanical parts). If anyone has ideas on the Bibliography as well, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search for any internal mechanisms? Or did you break apart one of them to see what mechanism and parts are in there ? This is a good question but it can be improved and help others help you better if it includes what has already been searched, and what to focus on.

Comment: what component parts are not mechanical or electrical? my blender - which I have had apart as i got it from the scrap and fixed it.. - does not have any software, lcd display etc etc Perhaps if you get hold of a couple and take them apart it may help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. My research has still not reached the depth of the internal mechanisms yet; I first need to clarify what type of mechanical/electrical parts are used (e.g. Universal Motor or Induction Motor) and which particular industrial processes are used to construct them, and then I will try to explore further on the internal divisions of the device. For non-mechanical parts, I was thinking of the jar and the lid of the bender.

Comment: You may find this video interesting: (NSFW language) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lA0kiYqyBmo

Answer (score 0):

for low speed blenders like food processors, typical motors are induction type, as used in electric fans or table saws. for high speed blenders for crushing ice for drinks and so forth, brush-type AC motors are used, as in old-style (corded, 120VAC) electric drills.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know perhaps what kind of Induction Motors are used for low-power blenders? Are they split-phase (resistance-start) or capacitor start or two-capacitor motors?

Comment: sorry, I do not know!

Answer (score 0):

As niels said, they have all induction motors, some advanced kitchen equipments has also a safety coupling.

For instance if you want crush nuts on your smoothie but the nuts are too hard to crush by the baldes, safety coupling (automatic engagement) disengage the motor and the driven shaft to protect sensitive components of motor, baldes or ... .

They also have another coupling in serie with the safety coupling, it is called the magnetic coupling (only in recent applications) to couple the motor and the driven shaft, as far as you keep pressing the button, friction disc of magnetic coupling get engage with driving shaft (motor) and the driven shaft (blades). Old food processors use another type of conventional coupling. If you can drive the motor manually by rotating it with your hand it's not a magnetic coupling.

At the driven end of magnetic coupling there is a crown wiel (negative or female) and a male part at the top of driven shaft which is connected via a polymer rod to the baldes, this maple and female part fit together to complete the the torque transmission.

There exist many variants of mechanisms, but they share the same principal. All of them have at least an induction motor, a coupling and blades.